# Which is more soluble in water ammonia or Sodium dodecyl sulfate

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, kinetics, solubility

I've tried looking this up and can't seem to find the solubility of SDS if any one knows the answer I would really appreciate it.

Which is more soluble in water ammonia or Sodium dodecyl sulfate.

Thanks,

Comment: en:wp actually doesn't have a number, but https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natriumlaurylsulfat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDS water solubility is 100g/L according to this source https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Sodium_dodecyl_sulfate#section=Solubility

Ammonia's maximum concentration in water is 880g/L at just above 0C [data here](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/gases-solubility-water-d_1148.html)